# Tkinter: How to prevent contents from previous searches appearing on a forthcoming search

Tags: python, tkinter, logic

currently working on an API-based F1 drivers' app using Python and Tkinter.

The issue I'm facing is that contents from previous searches appear on forthcoming content.

Visually, the issue can be best represented here, where the new content appears on top of the old content, which is no good.

[image: Issue_at_Hand]

To solve this problem, I know that logically, there should be some approach where when user presses `search_button`, the button should be attempting to clear the previous search's content in `main_frame` and then recreate `main_frame` with the new content.

Generally, it's not too difficult to clear content in a frame, since that's through using w_info and the .destroy() method, but I don't know how to recreate a frame with new content. In other words, I'm having trouble programming out the logic (perhaps the logic should be clearer or there should be different logic)

Here's the code:

```
#Go to

from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from tkinter import messagebox
import requests
import json

root = Tk()
root.geometry("800x300")
root.title("F1 Desktop Application")
root.iconbitmap("formula1_logo.ico")




#generate 2022 drivers-list [can scale to drivers-list by changing the]
drivers_list_request = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/2022/drivers.json")
#initialize empty-list
drivers_list = []
drivers_list_object = json.loads(drivers_list_request.content)

for elements in drivers_list_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"]:
    drivers_list.append(elements["givenName"] + " " + elements["familyName"])


# Update the Entry widget with the selected item in list
def check(e):
    
    v= entry_box.get()

    if v=='':
        hide_button(menu)
    
    else:
        data=[]
        for item in drivers_list:
            if v.lower() in item.lower():
                data.append(item)
        
        update(data)
        show_button(menu)

def update(data):
   # Clear the Combobox
   menu.delete(0, END)
   # Add values to the combobox
   for value in data:
        menu.insert(END,value)
        
def fillout(event):
    
    try:
        
        entry_box.delete(0,END)
        
        entry_box.insert(0,menu.get(menu.curselection()))
        
        hide_button(menu)
        
    #handle a complete deletion of entry-box via cursor double tap
    except:
        
        pass
        
def hide_button(widget):
    widget.grid_remove()
    
def show_button(widget):
    widget.grid()
    
    
def full_name():
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()    

    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}.json".format(lower_user_input))
    
    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
    
    name = response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["givenName"] + " " + response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["familyName"]

    driver_name_label.configure(text = name)
    
    
def team():
    
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/drivers/{}/constructors.json".format(lower_user_input))

    response_object = json.loads(response.content)

    team = response_object["MRData"]["ConstructorTable"]["Constructors"][0]["name"]
    
    team_api = Label(main_frame, text = team, font = ("Arial", 10))
    
    team_api.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
    
    
def driver_code(): 
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()    
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}.json".format(lower_user_input))
        
    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
        
    code = response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["code"]
    
    code_api = Label(main_frame, text = code, font = ("Arial", 10))
    
    code_api.grid(row = 3, column = 1, sticky = W)
        

    
    
def nationality(): 
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}.json".format(lower_user_input))
        
    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
    
    nationality = response_object["MRData"]["DriverTable"]["Drivers"][0]["nationality"]
        
    nationality_api = Label(main_frame, text = nationality, font = ("Arial", 10))

    nationality_api.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)
        

def wins(): 
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()

    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/results/1.json".format(lower_user_input))
        
    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
        
    wins = response_object["MRData"]["total"]
    
    wins_api = Label(main_frame, text = wins, font = ("Arial", 10))
    
    wins_api.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)
    
    
    
def poles(): 
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/qualifying/1.json".format(lower_user_input))

    response_object = json.loads(response.content)

    poles = response_object["MRData"]["total"]
    
    poles_api = Label(main_frame, text = poles, font = ("Arial", 10))

    poles_api.grid(row = 2, column = 3, sticky = W, padx = 15)
    

def podiums():
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()

    #podiums is sum of 1st, 2nd, 3rd place finishes
    
    #####DRY principle; let's reuse the code from wins()
    ######noticing how maybe should create a separate function which "places" the widget
    #######for now, reuse the code
    
    #1st place finishes
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/results/1.json".format(lower_user_input))
        
    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
    
    #convert wins to int
        
    wins = int(response_object["MRData"]["total"])
    
    #2nd place finishes
        
    response_ii = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/results/2.json".format(lower_user_input))
    
    response_ii_object = json.loads(response_ii.content)
    
    response_ii_amount = int(response_ii_object["MRData"]["total"])
    
    
    
    #3rd place finishes 
    
    response_iii = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/results/3.json".format(lower_user_input))
    
    response_iii_object = json.loads(response_iii.content)
    
    response_iii_amount = int(response_iii_object["MRData"]["total"])
    
        
        
    podiums = str(wins + response_ii_amount + response_iii_amount)
    
    podiums_api = Label(main_frame, text = podiums, font = ("Arial", 10))
    podiums_api.grid(row = 1, column = 3, padx = 15,  sticky = W)
    
    
    
    
    
def championships():
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/drivers/{}/driverStandings/1/seasons.json".format(lower_user_input))

    response_object = json.loads(response.content)
    
    championships = response_object["MRData"]["total"]
    
    
    championships_api = Label(main_frame, text = championships, font = ("Arial", 10))

    championships_api.grid(row = 3, column = 3, padx = 15, sticky = W)
    
    
def standing():
    
    lower_user_input = grab_user_input()
    
    response = requests.get("http://ergast.com/api/f1/current/drivers/{}/driverStandings.json".format(lower_user_input))

    response_object = json.loads(response.content)

    position = response_object["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["position"]

    points = response_object["MRData"]["StandingsTable"]["StandingsLists"][0]["DriverStandings"][0]["points"]

    standing = "{} ({} pts)".format(position, points)
    
    standing_api = Label(main_frame, text = standing, font = ("Arial", 10))

    standing_api.grid(row = 4, column = 3, padx = 15, sticky = W)


    
def grab_user_input(): 
    
    user_input = entry_box.get()
    
    lower_user_input = user_input.lower().split(" ")[1]
    
    return lower_user_input
    

    
def search():
            
    #slow run-time is simply due to the multiple api calls made
    #perhaps less-so due to not completely following DRY principles
    
    full_name()
    
    team()
    
    driver_code()
    
    nationality()
    
    wins()
    
    poles()
    
    podiums()
    
    championships()
    
    standing()
        
    show_button(main_frame)


    

    
    
    

left_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 275, height = 300)
left_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = SE)
left_frame.grid_propagate(False)

search_label = Label(left_frame, text = "Search Driver", font = ("Arial bold", 12))
search_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, pady = 10)

entry_box = Entry(left_frame, bd = 5)
entry_box.grid(row = 1, column = 0, padx = 35, pady = 40)
entry_box.bind('<KeyRelease>',check)

search_button = Button(left_frame, text = "search", command = search)
search_button.grid(row = 1, column = 1, padx = 15)

menu= Listbox(left_frame, height = 7)
menu.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
menu.bind("<<ListboxSelect>>",fillout)





main_frame = LabelFrame(root, width = 575, height = 300)
main_frame.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = SE)
main_frame.grid_propagate(False)

driver_name_label = Label(main_frame, text = "Driver", font = ("Arial", 15))
driver_name_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0,pady = 30)

team_label = Label(main_frame, text = "TEAM", font = ("Arial", 10))
team_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

nationality_label = Label(main_frame, text = "NATIONALITY", font = ("Arial", 10))
nationality_label.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

driver_code_label = Label(main_frame, text = "DRIVER CODE", font = ("Arial", 10))
driver_code_label.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

wins_label = Label(main_frame, text = "WINS", font = ("Arial", 10))
wins_label.grid(row = 4, column = 0, sticky = W)

podiums_label = Label(main_frame, text = "PODIUMS", font = ("Arial", 10))
podiums_label.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 15)

poles_label = Label(main_frame, text = "POLES", font = ("Arial", 10))
poles_label.grid(row = 2, column = 2, sticky = W, padx = 15)

world_championships_label = Label(main_frame, text = "WORLD CHAMPIONSHIPS", font = ("Arial", 10))
world_championships_label.grid(row = 3, column = 2, padx = 15, sticky = W)


current_standing_label = Label(main_frame, text = "F1 2022 STANDING", font = ("Arial", 10))
current_standing_label.grid(row = 4, column = 2, padx = 15, sticky = W)









hide_button(menu)
hide_button(main_frame)

root.mainloop()
```

Would appreciate the help! If there are any follow-up questions for clarity, let me know!

Thanks, Safwan

Comment: Create those labels outside the functions and then update their text inside the functions.

Comment: Hey there! Thank you for replying.

So are you saying to create an empty-text label and then .config it in the corresponding function right?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean.